# pulseaudio not recognizing mic sof-glkda7219max 22.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headphones

I have a sof-glkda7219max integrated sound card, and pulseaudio does not, by default, recognize my mic (nor does it recognize when headphones are plugged in, but that is not important to me). up until about this morning, I had been using this .sh script to force pulse to recognize the mic:

https://pastebin.com/6uVzPjCb

I had turned off my laptop last night, and when it rebooted, the .sh script stopped working. I have tried to restart pulse, but I get an error that there is no process running:

> killall pulseaudio

> pulseaudio: no process found

When I try to start pulse, I also get an error:

> pulseaudio

> E: [pulseaudio] socket-server.c: bind(): Address already in use

> E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-native-protocol-unix" (argument: ""): initialization failed.

> E: [pulseaudio] module-rescue-streams.c: module-rescue-stream is obsolete and should no longer be loaded. Please remove it from your configuration.

> E: [pulseaudio] main.c: D-Bus name org.pulseaudio.Server already taken.

I have deleted the config.pa files in both /etc/.pulse, and /home/.pulse as I saw in other similar issues and it has had no effect.

Can anyone provide some insight into why pulse is no longer working with the script? I need to have a working microphone.

Thanks

edit: there is a detailed writeup with the script here:
https://old.reddit.com/r/chrultrabook/comments/ui6ghn/workaround_for_glk_audio_sofglkda7219max/

and a discussion here:

https://github.com/cb-linux/breath/issues/29

output of .sh file:

https://pastebin.com/jpHfNjK4

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: 22.10. I uninstalled pipewire immediately as it did not recognize the card at all.

Comment: You may want to report this as a bug. https://ubuntu.com/blog/the-keys-to-successful-bug-reporting

Comment: I used dos2unix on the script, and it works again. no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I used dos2unix on the script, and it works again.